# mysql でディレクトリ下のファイルを一括でインポートしたい。

Tags: mysql, shell

以下のようなdbディレクトリ下にあるファイル全てを一括でmysqlにインポートする方法が思いつかないため教えていただきたいです。
私としては`ls -1 db`でファイル名一覧を取得して上手いことできないかなと考えましたが、いい方法が思いつきませんでした。

```sql
db
├── 1.sql
├── 2.sql
├── 3.sql
└── 4.sql
```

「こうすればいいんじゃないか？」というご意見、アイデア大募集です！
質問者として可能な限り迅速に対応しますので、回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/cm5c9yqrvb11u5) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite のデータベースファイルを `data.db` だとして、`xargs` を使う場合。

```bash
$ find db -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sql' | xargs -I@ sh -c 'sqlite3 data.db < @'
```

Comment: metropolisさんありがとうございます！
こちらの方法を参考にやってみます！
できましたらまた改めてコメントさせていただきます！

Comment: 解決いたしました！ありがとうございました！